# Python Logging - Apply formatter globally

Tags: python, logging

I use phrase `!Silent` to determine where the log record will be saved.
If log record message contains `!Silent` at the beginning of string, my `Filter` subclass rejects this message in a `StreamHandler`. But message is passed to other handlers such as `FileHandler` or `MemoryHandler`, and is passed with `!Silent` phrase.

I created simple `Formatter` subclass to strip this phrase, including white characters on beginning of string, but I have trouble with applying this formatter to handlers.

In many places of my application i modify root logger handlers, creating, adding and removing it. Each of these handlers should have my `Formatter` subclass, but adding manually to each of it is little uncomfortable.

I looking for way to apply Formatter class globally to root logger, or overwrite root logger `addHandler` method to add filter to handler before adding it to root logger. Or simpler way if exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I am not sure I fully understood your question, so forgive me if my answer is not what you are lookng for... yet, instead applying a filter on the input of every handler, I would add a property to the unicode (or string) object that you are passing around. Something like:

```
>>> class LogMsg(unicode):
...      def __new__(cls, string_):
...         if string_[:7] == '!Silent':
...             cls.nolog = True
...             return super(LogMsg, cls).__new__(cls, string_[7:])
...         else:
...             cls.nolog = False
...             return super(LogMsg, cls).__new__(cls, string_)
... 
>>> a = LogMsg('The hard drive is on fire!')
>>> a
u'The hard drive is on fire!'
>>> a.nolog
False
>>> b = LogMsg('!SilentMy feet stink! :(')
>>> b
u'My feet stink! :('
>>> b.nolog
True
```

This way you could simply pass around 'string' that never display `!Silent` but has an hidden flag (`nolog`) that you can test only in case you need to.

HTH,
/mac